# Include a header from Excel in a for loop with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to include a header when printing data in a column.

#### Issue

But when I try it an error comes up:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

#### Code

```py
def pm1():
    for cell in all_columns[1]:
        power = (cell.value)

        if x < power < y:
            print(f"{power}")
        else:
            print("Not steady")
pm1()
```

I know you cannot compare an string with operation values.

How can I include the header while looping throughout the entire column?

Comment: ``power = float(cell.value)`` ?

Comment: For some reason there's an error saying the string could not be convereted to float.

Comment: Well, then sanitize your inputs. Print the cell value, and you will see what's in the cell that cannot be converted to a float. You may have to handle empty strings separately.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what that means. I'm fairly new to python

Comment: Check whether the cell contains a number or not.

Comment: The cell does not contain a number. My goal is to extract 100s of data points however a header (which is a string) is needed in order to label the column

Comment: Please read [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and accept any solving answer or comment on answer explaining why it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand from your comments, this may work for you.

```
def pm1():

    for cell in all_columns[1]:
        for thing in cell:
            # in openpyxl you can call on .row or .column to get the location of your cell
            # you said you wanted to print the header (row 1), a sting
            if thing.row == 1:
                print(thing.value)
            else:
                # you said that the values under the header will be a digit 
                # so now you should be safe to set your variable and make a comparison
                power = thing.value
    
                if x < power < y:
                    print(f"{power}")
                else:
                    print("Not steady")
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are looping through all cells of a column, here given by a first column `all_columns[1]`.

Assume the first cell of each column might contain a header which has a value is of type string (`type(cell.value) == str`).

Then you have to possibilities:

1. Given the first cell of each column (in row 1) is a header, take advantage of that position
2. If all other cells contain numerical values, you can handle only the `str` values differently as supposed headers

```
def power_of(value):
    # either define boundaries x,y here or global
    power = float(value)  # defensive conversion, some values might erroneously be stored as text in Excel
    if x < power < y:
        return f"{power}"
    return "Not steady"  # default return instead else


def pm1():
    for cell in all_columns[1]:
        if (cell.row == 1):   # assume the header is always in first row
            print(cell.value)  # print header
        else:
            print(power_of(cell.value))

pm1()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I could send you my bank account I would

Comment: @kingjcp44 Appreciate your feedback! Rather consider voting/accepting and invest in knowledge instead ️